# Resource Type vs Resource in Concource CI

Tags: concourse, concourse-pipeline, concourse-fly, concourse-resource-types

I am new to [Concourse](https://concourse-ci.org/)

Can someone please help me understand the difference between Resource and Resource Type in simple words?

Apparently, documentation is not helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about a resource as an object and a resource type as a class.

Resource types are docker images that can take a bunch of source parameters.

Resources are instantiations of these images with specific parameters.

Resources generate versions which can serve as inputs or outputs of your tasks.

For example, a built-in resource type `git` can be instantiated into a resource `code-repo` by taking a specific github URI and branch as params.

From here on out, every time a commit shows up in the `code-repo` resource it may serve as an input to tasks in a job.